# Java. Input array in function without initialising the array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to pass a `int[][][]` to a method `points_of_game` (and a `int[][]`) without first initialising the `int[][][]` as another variable.

My Code :

```
int[][] original_map = new int[9][9];
int[][] current_map = new int[9][9];
int[][] initial_map = new int[9][3];
.....
.....
.....
// INITIALISING THE int[][][] WITH THE VARIABLE return_maps WHICH I WANT TO AVOID.
int[][][] return_maps = {this.original_map, this.current_map};
points_of_game(return_maps, this.initial_map);
```

What I want:

```
int[][] original_map = new int[9][9];
int[][] current_map = new int[9][9];
int[][] initial_map = new int[9][3];
.....
.....
.....
// SOMETHING SIMILAR TO BELOW.
points_of_game({this.original_map, this.current_map}, this.initial_map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
points_of_game(new int[][][]{this.original_map, this.current_map}, this.initial_map);
```

Or if you change you method signature to:

```
points_of_game(int[][] initial, int[][]... boards) {
    // boards has type int[][][]
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
points_of_game(this.initial_map, this.original_map, this.current_map);
```

Comment: Thanks. That was just the thing I was missing. Wasn't able to find it online

Comment: *"Wasn't able to find it online"* - Have you tried a textbook?  I am being serious here.  Searching the web only works if you can express your "question" as something that matches the terminology that other people use.  A text book ... well you can just read it cover to cover

Comment: Which textbook?

Comment: Any textbook on Java programming.  (Hint: try searching in Amazon.com, look for the popular ones, read the reviews, the ToCs, etc.)

Comment: okay I will try those